# How to add export statement in a bash_profile file?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to learn that if I have to add export statement to set a variable in a bash_profile file . How would I do that ? For example if  I have to add export AX = 'name' then should I simply write it at the end of file or do I need to write anything else as well

Comment: quick note: do not put any kind of whitespace after/before the equal sign

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simply write `export AS='name'` anywhere in your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
# Append to the end of the file
$ echo "export AS='name'" >> ~/.bash_profile

# Update shell 
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

This first command adds the line you want to the file *(or just use a text editor)* the second updates the shells with the new variable.

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 scenarios:

**1. Exporting an independent variable**

For example if you want to export variable "AX" independently then use:

```
AX = 'name'
export AX
```

**2. Exporting an independent variable followed by appending it to some existing variable**

For example if you want to export variable "AX" independently followed by appending it to the class path then use:

```
AX = 'name'
export AX
PATH=$PATH:AX
export PATH
```

Comment: Thanks! The appending part was my question :)

Comment: do not surround the `=` sign with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, variables are declared and defined in one place and exported in another:

```
AX='name'
export AX
```

Comment: That exported variable has already been created . Should I just write export AX ='hostname' so that it gets set to this every time I login or still write the above way

Comment: where is it created?  if in your `.bash_profile`, then just change the place where it is defined.  If not, then your `~/.bash_profile` is the last one executed (at least in standard configuration) so just put it at the end of the file. (make sure it is after anything else that might be _sourced_)

Answer (score 1):

No need to define and export on separate lines.
You can write:

```
export yourVar="yourStringOrYourPathEtc"
```

Be sure to `source ~/.bash_profile` to see the changes work in the shell you are in. If in doubt, close the terminal and reopen it :)