# TensorFlow importing in Python CLI and IPython CLI but not in IPython QtConsole

Tags: python, tensorflow, ipython

I installed `tensorflow-gpu` on my system running Ubuntu 16.04. `import tensorflow` works well, loads CUDA on python CLI and IPython on the terminal. But on importing in `IPython QtConsole`, I get the following error.

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-41389fad42b5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     70 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     71 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 72   raise ImportError(msg)
     73 
     74 # Protocol buffers

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

The URL mentioned is a dead link.

I checked the env vars of the QtConsole and it didn't have the modifications I did in my `.bashrc` file. I changed the variables by using `!export $ENV_VAR=VALUE`. I later tried `!echo $PATH` but the changes weren't reflected. Strange O_o

I tried changing `os.environ` dictionary. That reflected my changes but still couldn't import `tensorflow`
How do I fix this issue?

EDIT: 
1. Importing tensorflow works on Jupyter notebook as well, but not in ipython QtConsole

2. I have tried running as `jupyter qtconsole` instead of `ipython qtconsole`, same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when I was trying to run my GPU-enabled Tensorflow on my Jupyter notebook. I had to fix two things, maybe they help you too.

**Jupyter Kernel**

Make sure that your jupyter kernel is the same as your venv/python environment you expect to run. You can find that out by running

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
```

If it's not (mine was pointing to .local/share/jupyter/kernels/), then there are two ways of fixing it.

1) You can edit the kernel.json file to point to your desired python:

```
$ vim jupyter/kernels/python2/kernel.json
```

2) You can remove the default kernel from your venv by running:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec remove python2
```

This will default to using the desired python on your venv.

**Tensorflow Setup error**

The pywrap import error is a [knwon issue.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7980). Because I didn't want to meddle with my installation (as it worked fine on python CLI, just not on Jupyter), the only suggestion that worked for me was to:

```
$ export PBR_VERSION=<your pbr version number>
```

This seems to be an issue with the setup.cfg of mock, which might be solved in a later release.

Goodluck!

Comment: I've remove the kernel, could you elaborate on the `PBR` part?
I don't know what that is or how to find the pbr version (`pbr.__version__`) gives me an error

Comment: You could run `pip list` from your venv to check what version of pbr is running. You can then add the export statement to your bash profile by doing something on the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524590/how-to-add-export-statement-in-a-bash-profile-file?rq=1).

I had to add `export PBR_VERSION=3.1.1` to my bashrc for it to work. Hopefully this helps ya!